# Parse all nested values

Tags: javascript, parsing, nested

Hi i have been able to parsed most of the values i need from the file but now having trouble in extracting the all values from a localizedSize in the nested array below:

[image]

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    for (var i = 0; i < info.objects.length; i++) {
    var counter = info.objects[i];
    var kickURL = counter.publishedContent.properties.coverCard.properties.portraitURL;
    var kickTitle = counter.productInfo[0].productContent.fullTitle;
    var kickDescription = counter.productInfo[0].productContent.description;
    var kickPrice = counter.productInfo[0].merchPrice.fullPrice;
    var kickSizes = counter.productInfo[0].skus;

        for(var j = 0; j < kickSizes.length; j++)
    {
        var sizes = counter.productInfo[0].skus[j].countrySpecifications;
    }

  console.log(sizes);
}
```

The above code just outputs this:

```
[ { country: 'GB',
    localizedSize: '6 (EU 40)',
    localizedSizePrefix: 'UK',
    taxInfo: { vat: 20 } } ]
```

looking to see if can get all values in localizedSize not just the first value.

Comment: What are you having trouble with ?

Comment: Hi, sorry on a very bad connection, looking to find a way to loop though all the sku array and extract the countrySpecifications[0].localizedSize values

So would be for example the output i would like:

Title: Nike shoe
Sizes: 3, 4, 5, 6 etc..

Comment: your code is not very readable - perhaps that's the issue

Comment: trying to make it a bit clearer

Comment: hopefully this is better to read..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the '0's in your code , they only fetch you the first item in the array

```
var kickDescription = counter.productInfo[0].productContent.description;
var kickPrice = counter.productInfo[0].merchPrice.fullPrice;
var kickSizes = 
counter.productInfo[0].skus[0].countrySpecifications[0].localizedSize;
```

Thats the reason you are getting only first size .
You can loop each item of the array in a for loop with the lenght property like you did earlier in the code

```
for (var i = 0; i < info.objects.length; i++) {
//.....
}
```

Otherwise I would suggest you to use for-of loop for array and for-in for objects when parsing over large JSONs .

Try the algo below merely reproducing your code(It may not be fully functional because mainly I am not aware of the use case , secondly the JSON provided is partial )

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
var info = JSON.parse(body);

for(let counter of info.objects) {
    var kickURL = counter.publishedContent.properties.coverCard.properties.portraitURL;
//console.log(kickURL);

    for(let prodInf of counter.productInfo){
        var kickTitle = prodInf.productContent.fullTitle;
        var kickDescription = prodInf.productContent.description;
        var kickPrice = prodInf.merchPrice.fullPrice;
    //console.log(kickURL,kickTitle);
        for(let sk of prodInf.skus){
            for(let conSpec of sk.countrySpecifications){
                var kickSizes = conSpec.localizedSize;
            //console.log(kickSizes);

            // if you want all the sizes in an array you can individually keep pushing each of the value to an empty array here or do whatever you like .
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i did it another way and yeah the [0] just gave me the first item. your method worked perfectly thank you so much!